# Adding mongodb extension for php 5.6 (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mongodb, dll

I have read few post here on solving my issue but neither works for php-5.6.

I downloaded ***php_mongo-1.6.8.zip*** and ***php_mongo-1.6.7.zip*** and tried all the .dll extensions and all of them gives one or the other error.

**Error message:**

1. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

   in Unknown on line 0
2. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

   in Unknown on line 0

P.S.: I am using *XAMPP* for my environment.

Comment: Please add the error messages that appear

Comment: @Jan please check my updated post. i have added error messages

Comment: It looks like you tried to install a 64-bit dll on a 32-bit machine on the first dll. Have you renamed the extension in your config for the second dll?

Comment: rename?? I am using a 64bit windows10 machine but xampp comes only for 32bit, the first error was for installing 64bit extention for 32bit xampp environment. But what about the second one, i am completely boggled.

Comment: You have to register the extension in your php.ini, right? So for the second dll it have to be `extension=php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll`

Comment: yes yes i have registered/loaded the extension. only after that i can get the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87559/discussion-between-jan-and-dhpratik).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I installed mongo extension with following steps:

- Download and install [xampp-win32-5.6.12-0-VC11-installer.exe](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.12/xampp-win32-5.6.12-0-VC11-installer.exe) to `C:\xampp` on Windows 7
- Download http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/1.6.11/php_mongo-1.6.11-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip, extract `php_mongo.dll` and copy it to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Add to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` line `extension=php_mongo.dll`

Without further configuration, I see mongo extension in command line (`C:\xampp\php\php.exe -i | findstr mongo`) but Apache complains about missing `libsasl.dll` and mongo is missing in http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php. Ok, what next?

- Copy `C:\xampp\php\libsasl.dll` to `C:\xampp\apache\bin\`, restart Apache and enjoy.

This howto worked for me well. I hope it will help to resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for solving my problem, it worked fine.my bounty expired, if u have any idea on how to revive the bounty please inform me.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow below steps to make Mongo work for PHP-5.6**

1. goto https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.14/windows
2. download php_mongo-1.6.14-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip
3. extract the zip file and copy php_mongo.dll
4. open PHP ext directory and paste the dll file
5. add the following line to your php.ini file
   `extension=php_mongo.dll`
6. restrat apache and test with below php code

---

```
// connect to mongodb

echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";

$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");

echo "Connection to database successfully";

// select a database

$db = $m->testdb;   // where testdb is already existing Database

echo "Database testdb selected";
```

**Note : Check the "mongo" module is loaded or mot using phpinfo()**

Answer (score 1):

In your **php.ini** file, uncomment this configuration, and restart your **Apache** Server:

```
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

If it doesn't work, try to put an absolute path to your extension directory, where `php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll` reside.

**UPDATE**

I have found this information in [PHP_OFFICIAL_WEBSITE](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows)
I think you should also add `libsasl.dll` to your **PATH** environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps described here:

http://devzone.co.in/configure-mongodb-php-windows-xampp-5-simple-steps/

User "kba" described the same steps. This steps should work. Just do everything that's indicated there.

Comment: For all the haters who downvote - please also add a comment saying what is wrong in my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, but noticed your link does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is not working anymore, but it worked well when I shared it.