# phpinfo() and pecl search mongo shows different version of mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed **MongoDB** on my local pc referring below site

http://linuxforever.info/2017/04/13/how-to-install-mongodb-3-4-in-linux-mint-18-ubuntu-16-04/

I made a simple demo of MongoDB and when I ran the project I got an error like

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::isDefault()

I have checked MongoDB version on both side (phpinfo.php and terminal) it's different.

Terminal => `pecl search mongo` command

`Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
 Package Stable/(Latest) Local
 mongo   1.6.16 (stable)       MongoDB database driver
 mongodb 1.4.3 (stable)  1.4.3 MongoDB driver for PHP`

Phpinfo =>

`MongoDB extension version  1.2.9
 MongoDB extension stability    stable
 libbson bundled version    1.5.5
 libmongoc bundled version  1.5.5`

Please help me to clear this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `pecl search` tells you what packages are available, not which ones are installed…

Comment: Try pecl install mongo

Comment: Then try reading the documentation, because `pel install mongo` is only "part" of the required install. If you want to work with any code using a driver then it should be the installed `composer` package in addition to that. See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: linux mint 18.01 and Ampps

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$con = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// Creating Database
$db = $con->yourdbname;
// Creating Document
$collection = $db->employee;
// Insering Record
$collection->insertOne( [ 'name' =>'Peter', 'email' =>'peter@abc.com'] );
// Fetching Record
$record = $collection->find( [ 'name' =>'Peter'] );
foreach ($record as $employe) {
   echo $employe['name'], ': ', $employe['email']."<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

please check this screen short

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing using following command :

```
  pecl install mongodb
```

Add extension to your php.ini file at the end

```
extension = mongodb.so
```

Restert your php and apache server

Use composer to load mongo db packages

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Run following code after above process

```
    <?php  
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  
// Creating Connection  
$con = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");  
// Creating Database  
$db = $con->yourdbname;  
// Creating Document  
$collection = $db->employee;  
// Insering Record  
$collection->insertOne( [ 'name' =>'Peter', 'email' =>'peter@abc.com' ] );  
// Fetching Record  
$record = $collection->find( [ 'name' =>'Peter'] );  
foreach ($record as $employe) {  
echo $employe['name'], ': ', $employe['email']."<br>";  
}
```

Comment: it's give error like
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::isDefault()

Comment: @YogeshDobariya First you need to use composer to load library

Comment: @YogeshDobariya , Have you added , extension = mongodb.so ,in php.ini file

Comment: try restarting your php and apache

Comment: it's same like you given above

Comment: which php version you are using?

Comment: 5.6 PHP version

my composer.json file is

{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "ext-mongo": "1.6.16"
        }
    }
}

Comment: are you using php7 because this code only work with php7

Comment: upgrade to php7

Comment: check this link for php5.6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134416/adding-mongodb-extension-for-php-5-6-xampp

Comment: I use linux pc and Ampps for local server

Answer (score 0):

`MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::isDefault()` was introduced in [ext-mongodb 1.3](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-writeconcern.isdefault.php)

You have `MongoDB extension version  1.2.9` as you shared output of `phpinfo()`.

You need to update the extension.

**UPDATE**

You can download latest extension from following link

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

**Linux Mint** is Debian based and you can install following package on it to upgrade
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/php-mongodb_1.3.4-1build1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: linux mint 18.01

Comment: PHP Version? using LAMP?

Comment: php 5.6 and Ampss

Comment: I try this  "sudo pecl upgrade mongodb" but it's give to nothing to upgrade

Comment: The link is not only for windows. You need to do make

Comment: where i add this mongodb-1.4.3.tgz files or how i run this?

Comment: you have any solution for upgrade extension please help me

Comment: @YogeshDobariya I have updated my answer again. I hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, @Hassaan I try this https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/php-mongodb_1.3.4-1build1_amd64.deb.html but it gives me an error. please review the screen short

i upload screen short

Comment: @YogeshDobariya let me try update this on my system today. Then I will provide you steps

Comment: @YogeshDobariya Update your question instead of adding new answers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I solved after several hours. Hopefully this saves others some time. I'm on macOS Sierra.

## Background

I ran `sudo pecl install mongodb` to update mongo driver. I didn't need to add the extension to php.ini because it was there from an older version.

PHP refused to recognize the updated mongo driver. I would also receive the Fatal error: Call to undefined ... isDefault() error when trying to execute queries.

## The fix

### Step 1

Find the full path of the *new* mongodb driver extension.

There are a few ways to do this.

Updating the driver (i.e. `sudo pecl install mongodb`) will output something like:

> Installing
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.2_13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so'

Alternatively, you could search for it: `find / -name "mongodb.so"` on Mac or Linux.

### Step 2

Locate your php.ini file. 
Again there are a few different ways.
Echoing phpinfo() in php will tell you where it is.
Alternatively you could run `find / -name php.ini`.

Mine was located at /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini

### Step 3

Edit your php.ini file, and replace

> extension="mongodb.so"

with the path to the new extension:

> extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.2_13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so"

### Step 4

Save and retry your query.

### More info

In my case, php.ini was actually including the mongo extension from /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini, so this was the file that I edited. However I successfully tested both solutions.